# Is it possible to eastablish two way communication between Android app and Jetson nano using USB?

Tags: android, usb, nvidia-jetson

I am new to this concept. I've tried searching for articles about this, but couldn't find any helpful one. I want to send some text data from an Android App to Jetson Nano. I've a few questions

1. I would need a USB Type C(Android) to Type A cable(Jetson) right? Can the simple charging cable be used for this
2. Should there be some python code running at the jetson end to receive this data continuously when Android device is connected to it via a usb cable.
   It would be really helpful if someone could provide relevant articles on this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, yes, you need a cable to connect the two devices together, but a charging cable might not be enough, you need a cable capable of transmitting data (which most "simple" charging cables are capable of nowadays).

On the data transfer side of things, [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-talk-to-usb-on-jetson-nano/164370/8) article might be of some help.